# Determine the set of all points where the Taylor series of the function $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$ around $x=e$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, contest-math

> Q. Determine the set of all points where the Taylor series of the function $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$ around the point $x=e$ converges to $f(x)$.

**My approach :**

$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=x^2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{(1+x^2)^n}=x^2 \frac {1}{1-\frac {1}{1+x^2}}=x^2 \frac {1+x^2}{x^2} \; \text {for} \; |\frac 1{1+x^2}| \lt 1 \; \text {i.e.} \; x \neq 0$ as the summation is geometric series.

$\therefore f(x)=1+x^2 \; \forall \; x \neq 0.$

Also $f(0)=0+0+0\cdots=0.$

Now $f(e)=1+e^2, f'(e)=2e,f''(e)=2$ and $f^{(n)}(e)=0 \; \forall \; n \ge 3.$

The Taylor series around $x=e$ of $f(x)$ is $(1+e^2)+\frac {(x-e)(2e)}{1!}+\frac {(x-e)^2(2)}{2!}.$

Thus the Taylor series is a polynomial on $x \neq 0$ and hence it converges to $f(x)$ on $x\neq 0$.

---

Is the solution that I have nwritten correct? Particularly I am shaky about the argument for the point $x=0$. I am confused whether $f$ is defined there or not.

Answer (score 2):

You are certainly correct in determining what the series converges to. But the convergence of the power series crucially relies on the convergence of the geometric series
$$
\sum \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)^n = \sum a^n,
$$
which does not converge for all possible values of $a$, but for a subset of them. For which $a$ does the series converge, and what does that mean in terms of $x$?

Comment: Yes I have taken this into account. It converges for $\frac {1}{1+x^2} \lt 1 \Rightarrow x^2 \gt 0$. Which means for $x \neq 0$. I noticed this and thus used the formula used for infinite geometric series. Are you trying to convey something else?

Comment: @Mathmore so you have demonstrated that the series converges for all real $x$ (since at $0$ is also does, as you demonstrate correctly.

Comment: At $x=0$, we have geometric series $1+1+1\cdots$. That's dangerous right? I am confused whether $f$ is defined at $x=0$.

Comment: @Mathmore Your series at zero is $$\sum_n \frac{0^2}{\left(1+0^2\right)^n} = \sum_n \frac{0}{1} = \sum_n 0 = 0...$$

Comment: Taylor series at $x=0$ converges to $1$ not $0$.

Comment: @Mathmore Actually the geometric series at $0$ will diverge, but you don't have to factor out the $x^2$ in that case to get a sum of zeroes as I did above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69345/discussion-between-mathmore-and-gt6989b).

Answer (score 0):

Precisely as you have calculated the function $f$, we see that at $x=0$ the function yields the value $1$ while the summation yields the value $0$ implying that the Taylor series converges to the function $\forall \, x\neq0$. Since the question  deals with convergence of Taylor series around $x=e$, we substitute $x$ as $(x-e)$ in the summation. Using the same analysis we say  Taylor series around $x=e$ converges to the function $\forall \, x\neq e$.

Comment: This is wrong. The OP proved that the sum of the series is $1+x^2$ when $\left\lvert\frac1{1+x^2}\right\rvert<1$. Therefore, the case in which $x=0$ was not covered. Besides, the Taylor series of a function abour $x=a$ **always** converges to the function when $x=a$.

Comment: So can we say here that Taylor series converges to the function $\forall \, x\neq0$ or $\forall \, x$ ?

Comment: Yes. That's true in this case.

Comment: Can you kindly justify how it is wrong Sir ? It will be of great help.  I have only made arguments with respect to the question only.

Comment: The first part of my criticism was not correct. In fact, $f(0)=0$. But that doesn't change the fact that $f(x)=1+x^2$ if $x\neq0$ and that $f(0)=0$. So, it is not true that the Taylor series of $f$ about $x=e$ converges to the functions when and only when $x\neq e$. It converges to the function when and only when $x\neq0$.

Comment: I totally agree with the first part of your argument Sir. I may not have been clear in explaining. What I meant was that since we have two values at $x=0$, $1+x^2$ cannot have the summation in question as the Taylor series (overlooking the condition for existence of limit of the summation). In the second part, I had a doubt (maybe silly though) doesn't Taylor series at $x=e$ not imply we substitute $x$ as $(x−e)$ in the summation ? If so then would the still convergence be $\forall\, x\neq 0$ ??

Comment: We *don't* have two values at $x=0$. Actually, $f(0)=0$. And the Taylor series of $f$ about $x=e$ is just $1+e^2+2e(x-e)+(x-e)^2$. It converges to $f(x)$ *except* when $x=0$.

Comment: Got it Sir @José Carlos Santos.