# find the set of all points where the Taylor series of the function around the point $x=e$ converges to $f(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

This  question has  already  asked here [Determine the set of all points where the Taylor series of the function $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$ around $x=e$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539825/determine-the-set-of-all-points-where-the-taylor-series-of-the-function-fx-s,,,,as)
I  want to  confirm  my answer whether my answer is correct or not??

> Q. Determine the set of all points where the Taylor series of the function $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$ around the point $x=e$ converges to $f(x)$.

My answer:

$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=x^2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{(1+x^2)^n}=x^2 \frac {1}{1-\frac {1}{1+x^2}}=x^2 \frac {1+x^2}{x^2} \; \text {for} \; |\frac 1{1+x^2}| \lt 1 \; \text {i.e.} \; x \neq 0$ as the summation is geometric series.

$\therefore f(x)=1+x^2 \; \forall \; x \neq 0.$

Also $f(0)=0+0+0\cdots=0.$

Now $f(e)=1+e^2, f'(e)=2e,f''(e)=2$ and $f^{(n)}(e)=0 \; \forall \; n \ge 3.$

The Taylor series around $x=e$ of $f(x)$ is $(1+e^2)+\frac {(x-e)(2e)}{1!}+\frac {(x-e)^2(2)}{2!}.$

Thus the Taylor series is a polynomial on $x \neq 0$ and hence it converges to $f(x)$ on $x\neq 0$.

---

Is my solution is  correct  or not correct ??

Comment: Looks good to me, and your flow is very logical

Comment: thanks  @YousefKaddoura